# Restlet HTTP problems in OSGi

Tags: http, proxy, network-programming, osgi, restlet

I'm a fascinated user of the Restlet framework (version 2.08). This is why I'm currently trying to use Restlet in an OSGi environment for the practical part of my thesis. Finally, I arrived to create a server bundle (which is started by the Activator in my Felix OSGi environment) and to show a message as a response to a simple call like `http://localhost:8888/`.

But I don't succeed to receive another resource from my Restlet. Imagine the case that I need data from `http://localhost:808​0/tripleStore/triple​s/5` in order to calculate the result of `http://localhost:8888/test`. (code snippet follows...)

```
public void startServer() throws Exception {
   component = new Component();
   Server server = new Server ( Protocol.HTTP, 8888);
   component.getServers​().add(server);
   Client client = new Client (Protocol.HTTP);
   component.getClients​().add(client);

   Restlet restlet = new Restlet() {
      @Override
      public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
         response.setEntity("Container Resource is active!", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
      }
   };

   Restlet restletTest = new Restlet() {
      @Override
      public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
         RdfClientResource cli = new RdfClientResource("http://localhost:808​0/tripleStore/triples/5");
         cli.setFollowingRedi​rects(false);
         Representation repri = cli.get();
         response.setEntity(repri);
      }
   };

   component.getDefault​Host().attach("/cont​ainer",new Sink());
   component.getDefault​Host().attach("/test​",restletTest);
   component.getDefault​Host().attach(restle​t);
   component.getClients​().add(Protocol.HTTP​);
   component.start();
}
```

Currently I'm getting a "bad request"-error when I call
`http://localhost:808​0/tripleStore/triple​s/5` in my restlet and a "forbidden"-error when I call `http://127.0.0.1:808​0/tripleStore/triple​s/5` from my Restlet.

Further research has shown that the cause for this errors is quite simple. The restlet tries to get it's results directly from the network proxy, which doesn't know any `localhost` and forbids the call to `127.0.0.1`.

Another critical point is, that the error was always replicable, except during one try. In this case, everything worked fine. This is why I assume a relation to the OSGi startup order. (Which isn't fix and depends on the Sonatype Aether-framework.)

Are you already aware of an error like this? And can you suggest me any bugfix avoiding to try all OSGi startup orders by hand? When I try to do these things outside of OSGi, everything works quite fine.

Thanks in advance!
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

Your problem remind me a problem I had. What you must have in mind is that client connectors are automatically registered against the Restlet engine. The problem here is the order in the bundle loading.

My problem was about the HTTPS connector. You must be sure that the bundle providing the connector is already loaded when trying to add the client connector. Otherwise I'll see something like that in the trace:

```
Internal Connector Error (1002) - No available client connector supports the required
protocol: 'HTTPS'. Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath.
```

Perhaps before adding your client connector can you check the loaded bundles and before executing your REST request, the registered client connector?

Here is the code to see registered client connectors:

```
List<ConnectorHelper<Client>> clients = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients();
System.out.println("Connectors - "+clients.size());
for (ConnectorHelper<Client> connectorHelper : clients) {
    System.out.println("connector = "+connectorHelper.getClass());
}
```

You can use OSGi bundle listeners to see if necessary bundles are loaded. Here is a sample of code:

```
// Checking the bundle loading in the future
bundleContext.addBundleListener(new BundleListener() {
    public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {
        if (event.getBundle().getSymbolicName().equals("org.restlet.ext.ssl")
                       & event.getBundle().getState()==BundleEvent.RESOLVED) {
            registerClientConnector();
        }
    }
});

// Checking if the bundle is already present
Bundle[] bundles = bundleContext.getBundles();
for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
    if (bundle.getSymbolicName().equals("org.restlet.ext.ssl")
              && bundle.getState()==BundleEvent.RESOLVED) {
        registerClientConnector();
    }
}
```

The registerClientConnector method simply does something like that:         component.getClients().add(Protocol.HTTPS);.

Hope it helps you. Don't hesitate to send me a minimal project to reproduce the problem so I can help more precisely.
Thierry